# Странный пробел из-за другого блока?

Tags: html, css

Помогите пожалуйста избавиться от непонятного пробела. Этот вопрос, скажем так продолжение предыдущего моего вопроса, т.к. я думаю понял откуда берутся эти пробелы. Я заметил, что когда я добавляю `div` перед `ul`, то под последним `li` появляется пробел. Без этого `div` все нормально.

[image: Пример ошибки]

Исходный код:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 50px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Поиск...">
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><img />Russia</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img />China</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img />USA</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img />France</a></li>
    <li><a href=""><img />Germany</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Почему этот пробел появляется и как от него избавиться? На компьютере есть проблема, на телефоне нет. На другом телефоне уже есть.

Comment: В чем проблема? [Скриншот](https://i.imgur.com/SJ5uz2o.png)

Comment: @OliverPatterson я скриншот выложил, у меня эта проблема есть. Могу скриншот полный скинуть, прямо со вставки с этого сайта, вдруг не верите мне. Вообще, я нашел похожий вопрос на другом сайте, и как там написано, связано это с масштабированием. С округлением пикселей и т.д. В принципе да, в этом проблема. Я приблизил немного и пробел пропал. Но как избавиться от него, на сайте не нашел.

Comment: А вы же пробовали через devtools наводится? Это полоска к чему относится?

Comment: @OliverPatterson у меня границы размытые в devtools, сложно понять. Но сейчас я заметил, что этот пробел еще и справа. Справа полоска вроде относится к `border`. По крайней мере на месте пробела оранжевая площадь, отвечающая за `border`

Comment: Я решил проблему, просто увеличив `border` между элементам до двух, и `padding` сверху и снизу до `12px`, но это очевидно не лучшее решение. Хотелось бы какой-то более универсальный способ. (странно, что раньше, за не маленький стаж работы, с этой проблемой не сталкивался)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в этом блоке, а точнее в `input`

```
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Поиск...">
</div>
```

У данного инпута присутствует бордер стандартный 2px, и как раз из-за него происходит данный сдвиг.